# How do I get the font size from the OS's accessibility features using Node or Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, accessibility

I am working on an Electron project and the specification states that the font size should adjust with the font size set in the OS's accessibility settings - this needs to be compatible with both Windows and OSX.

Is there a way I can get the font size to use as default and/or minimum font size for the electron windows, or should Chromium automatically take care of the scaling of fonts which have sizes set using CSS?

Finally, are there any special considerations I need to keep in mind when writing the CSS, such as using `em` rather than `px`?

Comment: This is a great question and I'll be watching with great interest. Out of curiosity, have you tried changing your font size on whatever your OS is and seen how it affects your app now?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the font settings on the windows system I am using; I will be confirming this with a colleague later today.

Comment: I'd be very curious how things scale if you, for example, set a div to `300px` vs `25rem` or something

Comment: @TKoL My colleague has confirmed that on Windows the font size does change, and other sizing (such as div sizes) do not - This is without needing any code changes, so in the case of Windows at least it looks like chromium does already take care of the scaling. *I would still appreciate any answers people can give as this has not been tested on OSX yet*

Comment: div sizes don't change even when you define them with `rem` or `em`?

Comment: We don't set any divs with `em` or `rem`, so it's a good question but I'm unable to confirm; our layout is flexbox with a mixture of `px` and `%` dimensions which are uneffected